# What is the word for "Meant to be understood by someone special"?

Tags: word-request

What is the word for "meant to be understood by only someone"?

Like,

> "Everyone could see his WhatsApp status, but only she could understand"

I want to know if there's a word for the thingamajig "only one could understand it"

Comment: have you heard the words cryptic arcane?

Answer (score 1):

The word you may be looking for is

> **insider**
>
> You wouldn't understand, it's an **inside** joke.

If there's a secret that only a few people know, the ones that *do know* are "***insiders***".

Answer (score 1):

A **coded message** is understandable only by someone who knows the code. This code can be literal (using a code-book or an encryption algorithm) or metaphorical (using words or making references to experiences that have a personal meaning to both the speaker and the intended recipient of the message).

Another metaphor that is sometimes used is a [**dog whistle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-whistle_(politics)).  A literal dog whistle makes a noise that is very high-pitched and is outside the range of human hearing, but within the range that dogs can hear.  A metaphorical **dog whistle** uses vocabulary or references that only a small, targeted number of people will understand. Generally, a dog whistle is meant for an entire demographic group (usually people with a shared set of beliefs), not just a single person.

Answer (score 0):

Jargon can be good choice.

**jargon** - *special words and phrases that are used by particular groups of people, especially in their work*

Answer (score 0):

***Esoteric*** is probably what you're looking for.

It's defined by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/esoteric) as:

> **Esoteric:** Intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest.
>
> Example: Esoteric philosophical debates.